# Create relationships from sequence of events

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a CSV with log of events that has following columns: `EventType`, `UserId`, `RecordId` (an auto-incremented sequence number). I want to import to Neo4j and build a node for every `EventType` (around 100 unique types) and then analyze paths using relationships. To build relationship I need to match all raw events and find the "next" event in the path, which means I need to match it with event that has same `UserId` and next `RecordId` is larger than the current `RecordId` (`next RecordId > current RecordId`).
What is the efficient way to do this in Cypher? Somehow I come up with queries that involve a Cartesian product, which are very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot avoid Cartesian products in this case. However, you can

1. Make them as small as possible.
2. Use indexing to improve the speed of your queries.

Besides using `EventType` as a node label ("unique type"), I strongly recommend to use an additional `Event` label for all events so that you can index the `userId` value and `recordId` values.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Event(recordId)
CREATE INDEX ON :Event(userId)
```

I created a small example data set:

```
CREATE
  (e1:Event:Skating {userId: 1, recordId: 1}),
  (e2:Event:Hiking {userId: 1, recordId: 2}),
  (e3:Event:Mountaineering {userId: 1, recordId: 3})
```

To get the next `recordId`, you need to satisfy that `nextRecordId > currentRecordId` and also the `nextRecordId` must be the smallest one (as the `recordId` comes from an auto-incremented sequence). We than connect the two events using `MERGE` (`CREATE` also works, but using `MERGE` makes sure that we avoid creating duplicate edges). This gives the following query:

```
MATCH (a:Event), (b:Event)
WHERE a.userId = b.userId
  AND a.recordId < b.recordId
WITH a, min(b.recordId) AS bRecordId
MATCH (b {recordId: bRecordId})
MERGE (a)-[:NEXT]->(b)
```

This query creates a Cartesian product for all user ids. As long as the users do not participate in hundreds of events, the size of the Cartesian products should not grow huge. Note that the first `MATCH` uses both indices (`userId` and `recordId`), while the second `MATCH` uses the index on `recordId`.

Comment: It is running very slow. 
Theoretically if I put all events in a balanced tree it can be done with nlogn complexity. If I create a hashtable of balanced trees per user and order tree nodes by recordid.

Comment: If you can write some code (e.g. in Java) to add the relationships, you can implement a solution that is miles faster - as you said, you can use additional data structures, such as hashtables and trees.